# How to send json object to action in C# in @Url.Action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am trying to send a json object to my action but I am not able to send it. Could anybody help me out with this. It is reside on some other controller

```
var pData = { id: null, StateCity: statecityName, Zip: zipcode, MaxDistance: maxdist, PhyName: phyName, ClickCnt: 0 };

window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Different", new { @pData=pData})';
```

Here `pData` is saying not found.

My action `DifferentController`:

```
public ActionResult Index(PData pData )
{
//some work
return view();
}
```

Comment: Do you absolutely need JSON in the url?  The QueryStringBinder can bind your model without using json.

Comment: how to bind that

Comment: Yes but in that case I cannot return the view I have to rediect to another controllers view after doing the process in this method

Comment: @raghav Well you can do that after the `AJAX`call is made- In the `success` function, you can do a redirect to your required `View`. I have updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: @raghav I have also updated my answer to if you want to use the `querystring` method.

Comment: "Well you can do that after the AJAXcall is made- In the success function, you can do a redirect to your required View. I have updated my answer to reflect this " but i need to do the search on the redirct page only

Comment: Ya I did it by query string, fact is one cannot send body without post and with post one cannot redirect to another view. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can not find the solution to send the Json object, here is a solution using query string which can work for you with page redirection

```
var pData = '?StateCity='+ statecityName + '&Zip='+ zipcode + '&MaxDistance=' + maxdist + '&PhyName=' + phyName;
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Different")' + pData;
```

And in your controller action method need to add all required parameters instead of complex object to bind

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string stateCity, string zip, int maxDistance, string phyName)
{
    //work with your parameters
    return view();
}
```

Add or remove parameters as per need in query string and action method parameter list. That should work perfectly for you.